# Get a child div from a parent div

Tags: jquery

my question is how can I get a child div from a parent div of a element?
Like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <button class="getchild"></button>
</div>
```

How can i get the div "child" from a div "parent" by hitting the button? (or any other action)

obs: get a element by $(".child") is not an option because there are a lot of other similar divs with the same class in the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the button's click handler:

```
$(this).parents('.parent').find('.child')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `siblings()`. This will get elements on the same level as the current element. http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Here's a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/4EayF/. Not sure what your deal is.

```
$('.getchild').on('click', function(){
   var child = $(this).siblings('.child');
});
```